# Gmail themes for Google Apps

Tags: gmail, google-workspace

I am using Google Apps free version. In the Gmail, I don't have themes. How can I use themes?

I followed the following address

https://mail.google.com/a/yourdomain.com/#settings/themes

as seen in [this link](http://downloadsquad.switched.com/2009/04/01/gmail-themes-finally-come-to-google-apps/)
but no luck.

Am I out of themes, because I am a free user?

---

ADDED

I do not see the "Themes" in the "Mail Settings".  I have checked with two Google Apps domain; both do not have Themes.  Am I the only one? How may I complain?

Comment: I've updated my answer, try this link: http://www.google.com/support/bin/static.py?page=guide.cs&guide=28576&answer=180095

Comment: @Greg Thanks for the link. I followed [Google help](http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1185265) and had to turn the functionality on. It works now!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Gmail click on **Mail Setting** and then **Themes**. You can choose from some pre-created one or create your own.

EDIT:

Try this link on which you have a button (Explore themes) to access the Themes settings under gmail (make sure you're logged in to gmail): http://www.google.com/support/bin/static.py?page=guide.cs&guide=28576&answer=180095

Answer (score 2):

Go to your mailbox, click the Gear icon in the upper-righthand corner, and select mail settings.  From there, select Themes.  I too have the free version and I can get to the themes just fine.